# Aplicação SPA em VueJS - Utilizar ou não Session?

Tags: session, vue.js, single-page-application

Estou iniciando com aplicações *SPA* (single page application) com `VueJS`. A dúvida é sobre o controle de usuários.

Eu utilizo `session` para isto ou não? Para eu saber o tempo que o usuário ficou logado, eu gravo esta `session` em algum lugar ou o próprio *Google Analytics* me dá essa informação?